# Pegar trecho específico de uma string

Tags: php

Tenho uma url do youtube e gostaria de pegar somente o trecho da variável "v".

usei isso: `$video = mb_substr('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4qVkWh1EAo', 32)`, me retorna o valor que preciso, mas gostaria de saber se tem outra forma.

Dá para acessar direto a variável "v" e pegar seu valor, é possível em uma string?

Comment: Chegou a pesquisar se já haviam respondido esta questão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o `parse_str` e `parse_url`:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4qVkWh1EAo";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $vars);
echo $vars['v'];    
// Saída: k4qVkWh1EAo
?>
```

> [**parse_str**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-str.php)
>
> Converte a string em variáveis

---

> [**parse_url**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)
>
> Interpreta uma URL e retorna os seus componentes

**Observação:** Não funcionará caso o `link` esteja no seguinte formato *https://www.youtube.com/v/k4qVkWh1EAo/*

Referência do SOen: [PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Comment: Bacana colocar a referência quando se copia uma resposta... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3393008/2072674

Comment: @KennyRafael adicionado

Comment: Mas a resposta não merece -2 por causa disso acredito que só uma sinalização em comentário ....

Comment: Adicionei também os `links` para a documentação dos dois métodos e a breve explicação encontrada no manual

Comment: Boa, funcionou!

Bem mais prático que a forma que eu havia feito.

Comment: @JuniorCastro só veja que coloquei uma observação no final, não sei se é o seu caso. Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Realmente, ninguém mais concorda que esta pergunta está duplicada?

Comment: Na verdade @Sorack esse campo será preenchido através de um campo de texto vindo do wordpress, sendo assim o usuário copia a url do link e cola la no admin, eu formato a saída. Assim não precisa do cara ir no youtube, incorporar etc...